# Использование паттерна Итератор

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования, итераторы

У меня всего лишь один вопрос: что является использованием паттерна итератора (С++), описание своего собственного класса Итератор, или использование, как я понял встроенного итератора, который объявляется типа:

```
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
vector<int>::iterator iter = v.begin(); //или и то и другое?
```

Comment: И то, и другое.

Comment: Смотря что понимать под "использованием". Можно использовать готовый код, спроектированный с использованием паттерна итератор, а можно использовать паттерн итератор для проектирования своего кода. Контекст вопроса не совсем понятен, но я все-таки склоняюсь ко второму ответу. Было бы странно утверждать что ты исползаешь/знаешь паттерн итератор только по тому, что ты пользоваться готовым библиотечным итератором.